# Angular: How do you implement a nested query tree to get comment sublists using observables?

Tags: angular, recursion, request, tree, pipe

From the ['Hacker-News' api](https://hackernews.api-docs.io/v0/overview/introduction) I get an object of type 'Story' using this interface:

```
export interface Story {
    by: string;
    descendants?: number;
    id: number;
    kids?: number[];
    score: number;
    text?: string;
    time: number;
    title: string;
    type: string;
    url?: string;
}
```

To get the comments from the instance I have this interface:

```
export interface Comments {
    by: String;
    id: number;
    parent: number;
    text: String;
    time: number;
    deleted?: boolean;
    dead?: boolean;
    kids?: number[];
    children?: Comments[];
    type: string;
}
```

And with the following service I am able to get the data from a 'Story' instance:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StorieCommentService {
    private apiBaseUrl: string = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getObservableDataStory(id: number): Observable<Story> {
        const urlReq = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/item/${id}.json`;
        return this.http.get<Story>(urlReq);
    }

    getObservableDataComment(id: number): Observable<Comments> {
        const urlReq = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/item/${id}.json`;
        return this.http.get<Comments>(urlReq);
    }

    getDataComments(ids: number[]): Observable<Comments[]> {
        const observables = ids.map(id => this.getObservableDataComment(id));
        return forkJoin(observables);
    }

}
```

And this is the component where I work the subscription to the queries and get the data.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main-comment',
    templateUrl: './main-comment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main-comment.component.css'],
})
export class MainCommentComponent implements OnInit {
    story!: Story;
    comments!: Comments[];

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private storieCommentService: StorieCommentService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadStoryData();
    }

    loadStoryData() {
        this.activatedRoute.params
            .pipe(
                switchMap(({ id }) =>
                    this.storieCommentService.getObservableDataStory(id)
                )
            )
            .subscribe(story => {
                this.story = story;
                this.loadCommentsData(this.story.kids!);
            });
    }

    loadCommentsData(ids: number[]) {
        this.storieCommentService
            .getDataComments(this.story.kids!)
            .subscribe(comments => {
                this.comments = comments!;
            });
    }
}
```

The theme is the following; what do I have to do to make nested queries and inject that information into each node of a comment?

Example:

##### Story instance:

```
{
    "by": "rbanffy",
    "descendants": 108,
    "id": 34867927,
    "kids": [
        34868970,
        34870281,
        34868786,
        34868687,
        34870529,
        34868307,
        34868283,
        34880950,
        34870434,
        34869068,
        34868279,
        34868490
    ],
    "score": 133,
    "time": 1676900294,
    "title": "AMD’s RDNA 2: Shooting for the Top",
    "type": "story",
    "url": "https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/02/19/amds-rdna-2-shooting-for-the-top/"
}
```

the 'kids' element has the ids to query each comment of the 'Story'.

##### Comments instance:

When querying with ' loadCommentsData' I get something like this.

```
[
    ...
    {
        "by": "fulafel",
        "id": 34868786,
        "kids": [
            34870372,
            34869337
        ],
        "parent": 34867927,
        "text": "...",
        "time": 1676905814,
        "type": "comment"
    },
    {
        "by": "avtolik",
        "id": 34868687,
        "kids": [
            34869971,
            34868808,
            34868803,
            34868942
        ],
        "parent": 34867927,
        "text": "...",
        "time": 1676905319,
        "type": "comment",
    },
    {
        "by": "bitL",
        "id": 34870529,
        "kids": [
            34870629,
            34870696,
            34871584
        ],
        "parent": 34867927,
        "text": "...",
        "time": 1676914950,
        "type": "comment"
    },
    ...
]
```

---

In each element of the list there is a comment, which in turn has sub-comments.

The interface created applies to add sub-comments, the problem is that I don't know how to make that call to each sub-instance of Comments.

Each comment has a 'kids' list (if there are comments) with which to perform subqueries.